# Number of prime ideals that contain a non zero ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, noetherian

In the proof of proposition (12.3) of Neukirchs Algebraic Number Theory, we use the fact that for a one-dimensional noetherian integral domain, there are only finitely many prime/maximal ideals that contain a nonzero ideal. I can't see why this is the case.

Comment: Hint:all such primes must be minimal.

Comment: @Alex Youcis: Because there can not be a smaller one since all prime ideals are maximal? And then use Noethers theorem that there are only finitely many minimal prime ideals above any given ideal? So, it is also true for the zero ideal?

Comment: No, it's pivotal that it's non-zero. Suppose that $\mathfrak{p}\supseteq I$, where $I$ is your non-zero ideal. Then, we can't have $\mathfrak{p}\supsetneq\mathfrak{q}\supseteq I$, otherwise $\mathfrak{p}\supsetneq\mathfrak{q}\supsetneq(0)$, which is ridiculous by dimensionality. But, this last step was obtained from the fact that $I\supsetneq (0)$-so this was pivotal. And yes, you can then use the fact that there are finitely many minimal primes.

Comment: Why is that ridiculous by dimensionality? Why doesn't it suffice to say that $\mathfrak{p} \subsetneq \mathfrak{q}$ can't happen because every prime ideal is maximal?

Comment: Every **non-zero** prime is maximal--which, of course, is by dimensionality.

Comment: Yes! I think I've got it. The prime ideals above zero aren't minimal since $(0)$ is a prime ideal below them, right? Thanks!

Comment: They aren't minimal over $(0)$, right. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Lemma 3.4 of the same book (that only require the domain to be Noetherian) you have that every ring $\mathfrak{a}$ contains a finite product $\mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2\cdots\mathfrak{p}_k$ of prime ideals, therefore if the ring is one dimensional, every prime that contains $\mathfrak{a}$ must be one of the $\mathfrak{p}_i$.